# Policies regarding extension cords

Tags: ethics, office-layout

Is it ethical to ask for extension cords if you're only going to use them to charge your phone? My desk doesn't have a free outlet and the company is cautioning against plugging our phones to our computers even if only for charging them.

I could buy an extension cord myself but my worry is I could be seen mooching off the company's electricity.

Comment: What are you doing that causes your phone to use that much battery during the workday? Unless it's PokemonGo, I don't understand. You could always buy a battery pack for relatively cheap and use it to charge your phone during work hours.

Comment: This was supposed to be a one-word comment:   _Ethical_ ...?

Comment: Some companies might perceive an extension cord to be a potential tripping hazard.

Comment: @DanPichelman Some companies (I worked for a major one) absolutely forbid outside equipment of any kind.  A poorly constructed USB cable could fry a computer's USB port, for example, that's without even touching on the corporate espionage and hacking concerns.

Comment: What does this have to do with ethics?

Comment: @myles:  Two ethical concerns, is it ethical to ask for company equipment for personal use:  Second, is it unethical to keep the reason a secret

Comment: @RichardU Nowhere in the question or comments does the OP state that he is considering hiding their reason for wanting this equipment.  Maybe it's implied but I don't see someone who is concerned about stealing company electricity to charge a phone being someone who would lie about why equipment is needed.

Comment: @Myles, as you said, it's implied.  You asked a question, I gave an answer.

Comment: *the company is cautioning against plugging our phones to our computers* Are you sure this is about power usage? My guess is that this is a weird security thing not a power bill thing. I also think that if they didn't want you charging personal devices at work, they'd simply say that and not make it specific to using your computer to do so.

Comment: Hello everyone, I'm not sure if ethical is the right word. As someone said above, I might be perceived as someone who uses a lot of his free time on the phone because it always needs charging. Also you are correct that the warning against plugging our phones is purely due to security measures. People charge their phones here in free electrical outlets on their desks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see no problem with asking for an extension cord. I certainly wouldn't bring my own in, because the company won't know where it came from or if it's certified (in some countries, e.g UK, lots of companies require that electrical equipment has to be tested and certified annually). The amount of electricity you're using won't even be a small blip.

Comment: Just as an aside, in the UK I'm pretty sure that PAT testing (the electrical equipment test for the UK) only has to be done once the item is more than a year old. Most places do this once a year, and may be happy to PAT test the item when its due dependant on the size of the organisation. I have a charger for my phone plugged into the company provided extension cable, and this was tested about a month ago when everything else was.

Comment: PAT testing! I was trying to think of what it was called, but it's been so long...

Answer (score 7):

It's absolutely ethical to ask. The answer will be one of "sure, we get an extension cord for you", "no, bring your own extension cord", or "in our company money is so tight that paying for the electricity to charge your phone will drive us into bankruptcy". In the last case, do *not* charge your phone at work, and look for a new job with a company with better finances.

A good company will always try to make life as nice as possible for the employees at the minimum possible cost to the company. Making your life nicer by paying you $100 more salary costs the company $100. That's expensive. Making your life nicer by allowing you to charge your phone at work costs the company pennies. So a good company will do all the things that make employees happier and only cost pennies. (Not all companies are good companies).

Comment: It certainly OK to ask. There are no ethics involved, however, unless the OP is planning to use the cord to strangle someone.

Comment: Actually, raising ones employees salary by $X costs the company way more than $X. [That is at least true for germany, as employers also have pay for health care and such. This probably varies from country to country.]

Comment: @nras And taxes that are tied to the amount of compensation. In the U.S., right off the bat there's social security tax of 6-something percent, plus unemployment insurance tax, probably others.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing unethical about asking, provided you are truthful in your request.  With hacking and corporate espionage getting more and more sophisticated, they will probably prefer you use one of their own cords.

I will emphasize that you do make it clear that the purpose is that you're out of outlets and need to charge your phone and don't want to connect it to your computer.

This serves two purposes, It clearly communicates that you are following policy and demonstrates your honesty.  Both of which will give HR a warm and happy feeling.

The concern about plugging your phone into your computer is not that the company is afraid that you will steal data, but that your phone could be infected by various means and used by hackers to penetrate their systems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything unethical about asking for an extension cord (or power strip).  I work in an IT department and we always have lots of these things, used, piled up in a box.  It can't hurt to ask, and the worst response you can get is "NO".  I'm sure that at some point, your boss or others at work call you on that phone - so it's a little grey, but pretty harmless.

However, since it's really for your own use I *do* think it'd be unethical to ask the IT folks to crawl under your desk to get it plugged in!

Answer (score -1):

No it's not ethical to ask solely for that reason unless your phone is a work tool or you give the reason. It's a very trivial breach of ethics, but still a breach nethertheless unless you specifically inform them that you want one just to charge your phone.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but I disagree. This is a trivial matter. But you might consider changing the emphasis of your answer; it *is* perfectly ethical if you tell them why you want the extension cord.

Comment: @KeithThompson yep, it's very trivial, but any sort of subterfuge or omission for personal gain is unethical, which is what the question asked. The implication of the question is the OP is NOT going to say why he wants it. And that's what other answers are suggesting he/she does. Seems clearly unethical to me, whether it's a $10 cord and 5c electricity, or a $20,000 gadget, the basic ethics are the same. So I'm just answering the question without hedging bets.

Comment: The OP didn't say whether he was going to mention the reason or not. What I'm suggesting (and of course feel free to reject this) is that rather than "It's unethical (unless you explain the reason)", you might say something like "It's perfectly ethical *but only if you explain the reason*."  (Incidentally, I'm charging my phone and tablet at my desk as I type this. I haven't bothered to ask permission because IMHO it would be a waste of time, which is far more valuable than the electricity. I understand your perspective, though.)

Comment: Point taken and changed the answer

Comment: I should also acknowledge that although the use of electricity is trivial, acquiring an extension cord is a bit less so.